# How to display sibling menu items in a menu object in DDRMenu

Tags: c#, html, razor, dotnetnuke, ddrmenu

I'm working with nav.cshtml in DNN's DDRMenu. On pages for this website, I'd like to display a menu at the top of the page that only shows the child pages of the current page, if there are any, and if not shows the sibling pages of the current page.

Here's the code:

```html
@using DotNetNuke.Web.DDRMenu;
@using System.Dynamic;
@inherits DotNetNuke.Web.Razor.DotNetNukeWebPage<dynamic>

@{
 var root = Model.Source.root;
}

@helper RenderNodes(IList<MenuNode> nodes)
{
if (nodes.Count > 0)
{
  <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
   @foreach (var node in nodes)
   {
    String isActive = "";
    string isDisabled = "";
    if (node.Selected) { isActive = "active"; }
    if (!node.Enabled) { isDisabled = "disabled"; }

    if (node.HasChildren())
    {
     <li class="nav-item parent">
      <a href="@node.Url" class="@isActive @isDisabled nav-link">@node.Text</a>
      <button class="submenuButton" onclick="$(this).toggleClass('active'); return false;">
       <i class="fa fa-caret-down" aria-hidden="true"></i>
      </button>
      @RenderChildNodes(node.Children)
     </li>
    }
    else
    {
     <li class="nav-item"><a href="@node.Url" class="@isActive @isDisabled nav-link">@node.Text</a></li>
    }
   }<!-- ./ for loop -->
  </ul>
}<!-- ./ node count -->
}<!-- ./ helper -->

@helper RenderChildNodes(IList<MenuNode> nodes)
{
if (nodes.Count > 0)
{
  <ul class="children bg-primary text-white rounded list-unstyled text-left ml-0">
   @foreach (var node in nodes)
   {
    String isActive = "";
    string isDisabled = "";
    if (node.Selected) { isActive = "active"; }
    if (!node.Enabled) { isDisabled = "disabled"; }

    if (node.HasChildren())
    {
     <li class="nav-item px-1">
      <button class="submenuButton" onclick="$(this).toggleClass('active'); return false;">
       <i class="fa fa-caret-down" aria-hidden="true"></i>
      </button>
      <a href="@node.Url" class="@isActive @isDisabled nav-link">@node.Text</a>
      @RenderChildNodes(node.Children)
     </li>
    }
    else
    {
     <li class="nav-item px-1 "><a href="@node.Url" class="@isActive @isDisabled nav-link">@node.Text</a></li>
    }
 

<!-- begin snippet: js hide: true console: true babel: false -->
```

Essentially, I need to figure out how to display the siblings, if the current page is selected but doesn't have children:

```html
if (!node.HasChildren() && node.Selected) {
    <!--Display Sibling nodes-->
}
```

Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: Shouldn't the siblings be displayed anyway, the way your menu is rendered?

Comment: For this menu object, I only want the siblings to show if there are no children of the current page.

Comment: Do you mean in the RenderNodes- or the RenderChildren-method?

Comment: In the RenderNodes. For example: @RenderSiblingNodes. Does that make sense? Thanks for the help.

Comment: So if I understand you right, you want have rendered: your active node & either it's children, if it has any, or otherwise it's siblings!?

Comment: That's correct.

Comment: I tried with as few changes of your Code as possible.

Comment: Does it meet your requirements?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not perfect in scripting Razorpages, but I'll give it a try:

```
@using DotNetNuke.Web.DDRMenu;
@using System.Dynamic;
@using System.Linq;
@inherits DotNetNuke.Web.Razor.DotNetNukeWebPage<dynamic>

@{
   var root = Model.Source.root;
}

@helper RenderNodes(IList<MenuNode> nodes)
{
   if (nodes.Count > 0)
   {
      //Check if the selected node is in the nodes & hasChildren.
      var activeNode= nodes.FirstOrDefault(n=>n.Selected);
      if(activeNode != null && activeNode.HasChildren())
      {
         <li class="nav-item parent">
              <a href="@node.Url" class="@isActive @isDisabled nav-link">@node.Text</a>
              <button class="submenuButton" onclick="$(this).toggleClass('active'); return false;">
              <i class="fa fa-caret-down" aria-hidden="true"></i>
              </button>
              @RenderChildNodes(node.Children)
         </li>

      }
      else
      {
        <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
            @foreach (var node in nodes)
            {
                String isActive = "";
                string isDisabled = "";
                if (node.Selected) { isActive = "active"; }
                if (!node.Enabled) { isDisabled = "disabled"; }

                if (node.HasChildren())
                {
                    <li class="nav-item parent">
                        <a href="@node.Url" class="@isActive @isDisabled nav-link">@node.Text</a>
                        <button class="submenuButton" onclick="$(this).toggleClass('active'); return false;">
                            <i class="fa fa-caret-down" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                        </button>
                        @RenderChildNodes(node.Children)
                    </li>
                }
                else
                {
                    <li class="nav-item"><a href="@node.Url" class="@isActive @isDisabled nav-link">@node.Text</a></li>
                }
            }<!-- ./ for loop -->
        </ul>
      }
   }<!-- ./ node count -->
}<!-- ./ helper -->
```

Is this what you need, or is there anything missing?

Answer (score 0):

Here's what we ended up with.

```html
@using DotNetNuke.Web.DDRMenu;
@using System.Dynamic;
@using DotNetNuke.Entities.Portals;
@inherits DotNetNuke.Web.Razor.DotNetNukeWebPage<dynamic>

@{
 var root = Model.Source.root;
}

@helper RenderNodes(IList<MenuNode> nodes)
{
 if (nodes.Count > 0)
 {
  <ol class="breadcrumb">
   @foreach (var node in nodes)
   {
    foreach (var child in node.Children)
    {
     if (child.Text == PortalSettings.Current.ActiveTab.TabName)
     {
      if (node.Parent.Children.Count > 0)
      {
       @RenderChildNodes(node.Children)
      }
     }
    }

    if(node.Selected && node.Depth == 0 && node.HasChildren())
    {
     @RenderChildNodes(node.Children)
    }
   }<!-- ./ for loop -->
  </ol>
 }<!-- ./ node count -->
}<!-- ./ helper -->

@helper RenderChildNodes(IList<MenuNode> nodes)
{
 if (nodes.Count > 0)
 {
  foreach (var node in nodes)
  {
   string isActive = "";
   string isDisabled = "";
   if (node.Selected) { isActive = "active"; }
   if (!node.Enabled) { isDisabled = "disabled"; }

   <li class="breadcrumb-item @isActive">
    <a href="@node.Url" class=" @isDisabled">@node.Text</a>
   </li>
  }
 }
}

@RenderNodes(root.Children)

<script>
 if ($('.breadcrumb-item').length > 0)
  $('.breadcrumb').show();
 else
  $('.breadcrumb').hide();
</script>
```